# Let's create a RandomFunction using 0 and 1

Tags: javascript

I asked you the last time, but I can not solve it.

I have a function that return 0 and 1 at random

```
const get_zero_or_one = () => {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (2))
}
```

I want to make a random function using the above function. But without Math.random (except get_zero_or_one used above).

```
const RandomResult = (max_number) => {
    let answer = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < max_number -1; i++) {
        answer += get_zero_or_one()
    }
    return answer
}
```

This is the code I wrote. Can I change to better code?

Thanks.

Comment: You want to create a function that returns a random number without Math.random()? Why? What is "*better code*"?

Comment: The code below will work fine if max_number is less than 10, but it will be inaccurate as the number of max_number increases. I want to solve this. - Obsidian Age Thanks. comment

Comment: how is it "inacurate"? give some examples, you are just adding random numbers, how can that be inacurate?

Comment: There seems to be a better code than the code I wrote that I found an interesting challenge in Korea but I can not think of it and I will ask you a question.

Comment: It's still not clear, if you just want to write the function in a different way ("better" is too broad, what you mean by better?) maybe you can ask here instead https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: if you asked for easier and better way, use `Math.random()`... if you don't want `Math.random()`, it's fine but it will make your life hard...you will be stress thinking about it... but it's fine if you still want to.

Comment: Oh good site recommendation thanks arieljuod

Comment: This will generate a numbers from a binomial distribution. So numbers in the middles of the range will be more likely than ones at the extremes. For example, trying it a million times yields frequencies like :`Map {
  0 => 1037,
  1 => 9689,
  2 => 43870,
  3 => 117163,
  4 => 204794,
  5 => 246309,
  6 => 204955,
  7 => 117661,
  8 => 43803,
  9 => 9730,
  10 => 989 }`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The `FastDiceRoller` algorithm described in  https://arxiv.org/pdf/1304.1916v1.pdf gives you a random uniform(ish) distribution.

Here's an implementation ripped from that paper using your function:

```
function fastDiceRoller(max_number){

  v = 1
  c = 0

  while(true){

      v = 2*v
      c = 2*c + get_zero_or_one()

      if(v >= max_number){

          if(c < max_number) { return(c) }

          v = v - max_number
          c = c - max_number
      }      
  }
}
```

Here be some frequencies from a million runs:

```
Map {
  0 => 100327,
  1 => 99930,
  2 => 100389,
  3 => 99824,
  4 => 100116,
  5 => 99999,
  6 => 99700,
  7 => 99957,
  8 => 99980,
  9 => 99778 }
```

Hope that helps.

Essentially it uses your function to build a binary number that is less than `max_number`.

Comment: Probably because you complained about getting a downvote, which isn’t relevant to the answer.

Comment: The complaint was added in response to the downvote, which prevented me from complaining in a comment.

Comment: Anyway, this was a common uni-level probability course question.

Comment: You shouldn’t complain at all. If you have a complaint take it up on meta, not in an answer.

Comment: Your answer has helped me. This is the first algorithm I've seen, but I'll refer to the pdf file you sent - Thanks glumplum